# What does "!!" explicitly mean in MSIL?

Tags: .net, cil

When a method is called in MSIL, I usually see the value `!!0` being passed a parameter, often multiple times in a row.

What does this mean, specifically, I assume it means *Pop the first value off the stack and push it as a parameter.* However, I was wondering if there was further clarification than that.  For instance does the first `!` mean something and the second `!` represent repeating the last step, in preparation for the next parameter assignment?

Explicitly, what does the `!!` operator do?

Comment: I believe it denotes a generic parameter, the number following !! being the zero-based index.

Comment: Possibly so.  I tried to search the spec but, you know, most online search engines filter out strings like "!!" when you enter them as part of a search term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Generic parameter in a method
>   definition, accessed by index from 0

As in [the ECMA specification for CIL](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf).

Section 11.7.1 - Types. It's ECMA 335, if the link becomes dead in the future something :)

So in human terms, it's a pointer to a type of the generic argument of a generic method. For types of generic arguments of generic types, you'd use `!0` (and `!1` etc.) instead.

Comment: Deleted former comment. I see now.  I was misunderstanding the spec.